# select multiple fields from most recent record from an oracle table

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

I want to do something like this:

```
select MAX(field1), field2 from tbl1 group by field1
```

But the above query as is doesn't work (sqlplus throws an error). How can I achieve above in a single query (for now, I have split it into two queries to get the result).

Comment: If you're grouping by `field1` but also aggregating on `field1`, what would you expect the query to return?  If there are 5 `field1` values, do you want 1 row?  5 rows?  What would you be aggregating if you returned 5 rows?  What would the `GROUP BY` accomplish if you returned 1 row?

Comment: Please post sample data and the desired result.

Comment: basically I want to select two fields field1 and field2 from the most recent record (field1 being the timestamp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an inline view and an analytic function (`max() over()`) in it for selecting the row(s) with the largest timestamp:

```
select field1, field2 from 
    (select field1, field2, max(field1) over() as max_field1
     from tbl1)
where field1 = max_field1;
```

Note that if there are many records with a timestamp value of `max_field1`, they are all returned (in arbitrary order).

Answer (score 2):

In Oracle 12, you can use:

```
select t.*
from tbl1
order by field1 desc
fetch first 1 row only;
```

Earlier versions require a subquery for the same functionality:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*
      from tbl1
      order by field1 desc
     ) t
where rownum = 1;
```

Note that the answer answer can return multiple rows, if the max is in multiple rows.  Your question is unclear on whether or not this is desirable.  These versions will return only one row.

Comment: The row-limiting clause (`fetch first`) in Oracle 12 is syntactic sugar for an analytic function (likely `row_number() over(order by field1 desc)` in this case), which makes it more concise, but (likely) equal in performance with the accepted answer. However, your solution for Oracle pre 12 is worse in performance, because it requires a sort which can be avoided by using an analytic function.

Comment: @MickMnemonic . . . Actually, the more important question is whether the OP wants exactly one row returned or multiple rows (if there are duplicate max values).  In my experience, often only one row is desired.  Of course, you can use `row_number()` to get the same effect.